# NotificationManager — How to make a notification do log "no" if not pressed within two hours?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, notificationmanager

I've set up a notification that appears in the status bar at a certain time. When you press it, it will log "yes" into a database. However I want it to log "no" if it is not pressed after 2 hours. I understand how to do the logging part, but I have no clues on how to invoke that scenario if not pressed within two hours. I know I can create two calendars to compare them, but again where would I put these? Any suggestions please? I've added some of my code below. Thanks!

Setting alarm code:

```
Intent intent_noti = new Intent(this,Nofi.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 12345, intent_noti,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), setTime,
pendingIntent);
```

Notification code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScanActivity.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("MedScan")
        .setContentText("2. You should take pills now")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.original)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
        .build();
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
        NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
noti.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
// Hide the notification after its selected
noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

notificationManager.notify(ID, noti);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `deleteIntent` with your notification object that will be called if the user explicitly `Clear` your `Notification`

So to achieve your goal you can do the following:

- When you display the notification, start alarm that will fire after two hours
- Handle the two cases in which the use clicks your `Notification` or hit `Clear` and cancel the `Alarm`
- If the alarm fires means your notification is still shown log `no` in the database